# AWS : The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssm

Running the lambda locally and I get the error.

```
AWS.config.update({
  region: 'ap-southeast-1',
  accessKey: 'xx',
  secretAccessKey: 'xxx',
});


{ UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid.
    at Request.extractError (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\json.js:48:27)
    at Request.callListeners (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (D:\Work\Amazon\BillingAggregator\billing-file-sender\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:115:18)
  message: 'The security token included in the request is invalid.',
  code: 'UnrecognizedClientException',
  time: 2018-08-03T08:21:29.493Z,
  requestId: 'e07f905c-0bbf-4508-8f79-ca0dc9348867',
  statusCode: 400,
```

Comment: It's better if you put some code here. I guess your .aws/credential file contains invalid access keys.

Comment: It says `The security token included in the request is invalid`. Where/how did you obtain the credentials?